# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Matrix<double>' to 'double

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have a matrix,called coordinatePointPrev which is 1X3 and there is another matrix called coordinatePointCurrFrame which is 3X1. anf finally a matrix called fund which is 3X3; all are defined as Matrix.

Now I want to multiply **coordinatePointPrev * fund * coordinatePointCurr** and save the results in 'resultOfEq' but for the 6th line, I encountered error saying "**Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Matrix' to 'double**";

Where I am going wrong

```
   Matrix<double> resultOfEq = new Matrix<double>(1, n);    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
 Matrix<double> coordinatePointPrev = new Matrix<double>(new double[,] { { a,b, 1 } });
 Matrix<double> coordinatePointCurr = new Matrix<double>(new double[,] { {c, d, 1 } });
 resultOfEq[0, i] = coordinatePointPrev.Mul(fund).Mul(coordinatePointCurr);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Mul` method returns matrix while you try to assign that to one cell of other matrix which is double.

what you seek is something like this

`resultOfEq[0, i] = coordinatePointPrev.Mul(fund).Mul(coordinatePointCurr)[0,0];`

This should pass compiler. But I'm not sure it will work (I don't know this specific library, but any other would crash on one of the Mul calls).

1X3 matrix (coordinatePointPrev) * 3X3 matrix (fund) = 1X3 matrix

1X3 matrix * 1X3 (coordinatePointCurr) matrix should produce error as you need 3X1 matrix to be able use multiply operator and produce 1X1 matrix which you most likely want.

So I believe you want one of them (`coordinatePointCurr`) to be 3X1:

`new Matrix<double>(new double[,] { {c}, {d}, {1} } })`

or you need to use different multiply order as columns of the first matrix must be the same as rows of the second matrix (and matrix multiply is not commutative (A * B <> B * A) )

Also I would remind there is no use of indexer `i` in the foreach so it basically does i-times the same (hard) computes to get i-times the same result and produce 1Xn matrix full of the same numbers.

Comment: I change coordinatePointCurr to 3X1 but the error persists. I believe it has something to do with conversion between Matrix<double> in opencv and double

Comment: the first code solves that problem. That [0,0] in the end is important.